# Adding unit measurement to Inputs

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to style an input in a way that it will accept only numbers but add any unit measurement(like kg, km, ...etc) right after the value. I do not want to use span because the unit measurement will appear when the user starts typing, and it will have one letter space between the number and the unit measurement. I am using typescript and react-hook for this.

I will appreciate, if we can limit the values, so it will not pass the width of the input. Also a version with Form.Control instead of an input(In case I want to do similar thing in the future with Forms).

[This is the how the end result should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d2s9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following html:

```html
    <input id="myinput" type="text">
```

This typescript should work:

```js
const input = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("test");
const addUnit = (elmnt: HTMLInputElement, unit: string) => {
  input.addEventListener("input", () => {
    elmnt.value = elmnt.value.replace(new RegExp(` ${unit}`), "") + ` ${unit}`;
  });
};
if (input) addUnit(input, "km");
```